# Invoke-SQLCMD fails on SQL Cluster

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to use the invoke-sqlcmd on a SQL Server Cluster but it fails to execute and produces the following error:

> invoke-sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The  server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to  allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) At
>   C:\rs-pkgs\SitecoreDeployScripts\SitecoreDatabasesDeploy.ps1:128
>   char:1
>   + invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile $inputFilePath
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

I am able to execute my script successfully on a development SQL Box that is not clustered. Here is an example of the SQL invocation:

```
$scriptPath = "C:\"
$scriptName = "MyScript.sql"
$inputFilePath = "{0}\{1}" -f $scriptPath,$scriptName
invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile $inputFilePath
```

So the question is this a Cluster issue or a security issue with remote connections not being allowed? How do I get the SQL Scripts to execute from PowerShell (the execute correctly if I open them in SSMS and press execute).

Comment: We can't see how you're making a connection to SQL server. the SQLPS module uses a PSProvider and since you're not supplying the destination explicitly in `Invoke-SqlCmd`, it's going to use the CWD.

Comment: Earlier in the script I use: Import-Module sqlps Is there a better method to connect/what is the correct destination? I thought the sqlps would work as is, it does in my dev SQL box, to pass through the windows authentication already in place

Comment: Tell us what the value of `$pwd` is when `invoke-sqlcmd` is executed. That is what is used as a connection to SQL server if you don't specify if (and in your sample you are not specifying). Otherwise, how do you expect that code block to know where your SQL server is?

Comment: So sqlps doesn't allow a pass through of credentials of the logged in user? This executes fine on another box, so I thought sqlps would pass credentials through. If not, what is the correct method to establishing the connection in PowerShell... and why does it work on another machine?

Comment: I didn't say anything about credentials or authentication. Look at the code you posted. How do you suppose the code knows where your SQL server is?

Comment: So, are you saying I need to declare the ServerInstance? Can you provide a sample/how would I revise my connection? Any clues why it works on the other machine

Comment: I'm saying that the cmdlet you're using, if connection information is not specified, uses the current working directory (CWD), to determine which SQL server to connect to. You're having a connection problem. But your code does not show where you're trying to connect. We can't see the value of your CWD. Therefore, show us the value, or determine what the value is, and see if it's correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108545/discussion-between-kode-and-briantist).

Comment: I opened a chat, as I am not sure how to find the CWD, and then where I would use this. Any samples are appreciated

Comment: Sorry I can't chat right now. I already told you how to get cwd, please re-read my comments: `$pwd`  (or: `Get-Location`  or: look at your powershell prompt).

Comment: All is needed was the -ServerInstance with the cluster name. It works now. It makes sense that it worked on the single instance

Answer (score 0):

In then end the script just needed the Server Instance name switch of -ServerInstance as follows:

```
$scriptPath = "C:\"
$scriptName = "MyScript.sql"
$inputFilePath = "{0}\{1}" -f $scriptPath,$scriptName
invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile $inputFilePath -ServerInstance 'MyClusterName"
```

I located the name by running the following query:

```
select @@servername
```

It works on a single box without the -ServerInstance switch since it is localized/single